# Expression-Blend-3 - Has Anyone Lost a Window? How Can You Get It Back?

Tags: expression-blend, expression-blend-3, window-management

Here's what I did:

- Right-clicked on an item in the 'Objects and Timeline' panel.
- Selected 'View XAML'
- Resized the window to a '0' size so that it went off the bottom of the screen.

Now, *even if* I:

- Select 'Reset Current Workspace'...
- Or restart Microsoft Expression Blend....
- I can't get the XAML view back.

> Can anyone help me?

Comment: +1 I cant help you but I can do what I do when the guy I sit next to at work does this and starts swearing. Point and laugh. I can't stand blend. VS all the way.

Comment: @grenade: Thanks for sharing. It *is* in fact helpful to know that others are experiencing similar pain. It's kind of a shame because the Visual Studio QA Team (Sara Ford) has a stellar reputation. I had/have high expectations for Blend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer from Unni, a PM on Blend:

> I think this is a bug we have fixed
>   for Blend 4.
>
> For Blend 3, the only workaround I can
>   think of is the following: go to the
>   equivalent of this folder on you
>   computer and delete user.config.
>   WARNING: Do so will get rid of your
>   settings and hence you might be
>   annoyed by a few dialogs etc. that you
>   had previously suppressed.
>
> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Expression\Blend3
>
> To be safe, I would copy the file
>   elsewhere before renaming so you could
>   replace it if that did not work out
>   for whatever reason.
>
> THanks,
>
> Unni